# Change background color of content panes in Shiny app?

Tags: shiny, background-color

I've made a Shiny pie-chart app using plotly. The app shows how much soybeans are exported from the port of Rosario, Argentina, to over fifty countries. It is queried by adding "/?COUNTRY=X" to the URL, and it is displayed in a website sidebar using an iframe. Everything works, except the background of my website is black, and I cannot get the content panes of the app itself to be black. By "content panes" I mean the background of pie chart itself and the background of the list of exporters below it. These remain bright white.

I have tried many things - such as adding *style = "background-color: black;"* in the fluidPage section - but everything that has been suggested affects only the background of the webpage and not the content panes. The working code is below, can anyone help with this?

```
#### packages ####
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


#### TO TEST LOCALLY, use "/?COUNTRY=X", eg http://localhost:PORT/?COUNTRY=CHINA (replace PORT with the appropriate port number). ####

#### load data ####
granos_exportados <- read.csv(file = "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ecotopia.today/Data/exportadores_rosario.csv")

#### shiny UI ####
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
  titlePanel(h3( "SOYBEANS", align = "center")),
  column(8, align="center",offset = 0,
         plotlyOutput("granos_exportados", width = "350px", height = "600px"))
)

#### shiny server or Backend ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  query <- reactive({ parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search) })
  
  output$granos_exportados <- renderPlotly({
    df <- granos_exportados %>% 
      filter(COUNTRY == query()[['COUNTRY']]) %>% 
      gather(grain_exporter, quantity, -COUNTRY) %>% 
      mutate(quantity_percent = quantity/sum(quantity))
    
    plot_ly(df, labels = ~ grain_exporter, values = ~ quantity, type = 'pie',
            text = ~paste(round(quantity/1000, 2), " toneladas"), 
            textinfo = 'percent',
            textposition='inside', 
            hovertemplate = "%{label}<br>%{value:,.2f} toneladas de soja<extra></extra>",
            marker = list(colors = c("#267278","#65338D","#4770B3",'#D21F75','#383689','#50AED3','#48B24F',
                                     '#E57438','#569DD2','#569D79','#58595B','#E4B031','#84D2F4','#CAD93F',
                                     '#F5C8AF','#9AC4B3','#9E9EA2'),
                          line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1))) %>% 
      layout(title = paste("Port of Rosario to", unique(df$COUNTRY)),
             legend = list(orientation = "h",   # show entries horizontally
                           xanchor = "center",  # use center of legend as anchor
                           x = 0.5),autosize = T,xaxis = list(showticklabels = F)) %>% 
      plotly::config(displaylogo = F) %>% 
      htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el,x){el.on('plotly_legendclick', function(){ return false; })}")
  })
}

#### RUN THE APP ####
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: image of shiny app with unwanted white background]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the backgroung by using defining `paper_bgcolor` and `plot_bgcolor`. Here's an example of plotly chart with transparent background:

```r
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 output$plot <-  renderPlotly({
   df <- iris %>% 
     group_by(Species) %>% 
     summarise(Sepal.Length = sum(Sepal.Length))
  
   plot_ly(df, labels = ~Species, values =  ~Sepal.Length, type = "pie") %>% 
     layout(
       paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
       plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
     )
 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Transparent plotly fig on cyborg shiny theme]

Comment: This worked perfectly. To change the font color of the legend items, I just added `font = list(color = "white"),` to both the layout and the legend sections.